# Sonar issue - Child class fields should not shadow parent class fields

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube, log4j

I have `Sonar` complaining about code quality issue. I have a class that is extending a `Spring` class which in turn extends few other `Spring` classes.

Is there any solution for this kind of issue?

**Sonar Reported Issue:**

```
"LOGGER" differs only by case from "logger" in "DaoSupport"
```

**AddressDao.java**

```
@Component
public class AddressDao extends PayhubNamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AddressDao.class);
    ...
}
```

**Spring class PayhubNamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport extending other classes**

```
PayhubNamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport -> NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport -> JdbcDaoSupport -> DaoSupport
```

**org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.java**

```
public abstract class DaoSupport implements InitializingBean {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- Spring -->
<spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>

<!-- Logging -->
<slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
<log4j.slf4j.version>2.0-rc1</log4j.slf4j.version>
<commons.lang3.version>3.3</commons.lang3.version>

<!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Just remove `private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AddressDao.class);` from `AddressDao` class and use the `logger` from `DaoSupport` class

Comment: Yes, you can rename LOGGER to AddressDaoLogger, or as Valentin says, use the logger of the base class. You could also ignore this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update guys